# FICO Score data & Data on FICO score changes due to Delinquencies

Tags: data-request

I am looking for 2 sources of data:

1. FICO scores (the larger the dataset the better)
2. How FICO scores change after an individual is delinquent on a payment (e.g. rent, credit cards, etc.)

I know that there are multiple factors for 2) so I am looking for a data set that indicates some kind of event, as well as the score before the event and the score post the event that triggered the drop.

Interestingly, there seems to be a lack of this data out in the open. I have asked on several forums but all I find is anecdotal evidence.

Does anyone have an idea where I could get these datasets?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Experian has this.  I suggest checking with them.

Comment: This is not available to the common person.

Comment: @dsmalenb I think the answer is appropriate. You will not find FICO score available publicly. Indicating which vendor has it is a good start.